# Should REST Get request return image or image URL?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

What's the best way to return image data from a RESTful service?

The image is part of a model (e.g. a User model which may have a 'photo' property) which is being returned by the method call.

Is it best to return the binary data with the GET request. Or is it best to return a URL from which the client can access the image.

The former seems like it would be easier to encapsulate and allow for authentication.

I'm using Django and the Django Rest Framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The GET response have more data than the binary file?.

- If the answer is Yes, you must return your data in response + URL
  with the binary in the json data.
- If the answer is No, you can return the raw image with the correct
  content-type.

In general, mix text data and binary data is a bad idea.

Django, as a modern framework, allows you to securize the URL's in a easy way.

Comment: The GET response has more than an image. For example, a person object is returned with properties: name(string), photo(image). From what you're saying, it's best to return the name and the photo URL?

Comment: It depends on the need, but in general yes. Think in your API as a generic API. If you have clients that don't use that binary data and your data have binary+text in response you're creating a unnecessary overload.